# Search for specific code string

Tags: html, css, string, file, search

Is there a way to scan a folder to find a string in HTML, CSS, PHP, etc?

Comment: Yes. simplest way is to use your OS's search abilities.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes, you may easily do so if you're on Linux.  You can use the commandline utility "grep".  Here's a [tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-grep-command-in-linux-unix/) you may find helpful.